# How to have a custom validation in MVC from a file that contains all the custom validations along with the validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4. As in my project I have a requirement that is to have a special file that contains various validation error no and their corresponding validation error msg. Then I want these error no to be defined in the model and on and such validation error I want my view to fetch the corresponding error msg from that file and display it in the validation summary.

Found a way to achieve the functionality by using `[Remote]` attribute. this is how I have done it.

The model CUSTS.cs

```
namespace MvcTest.Models
{
    public partial class CUSTS
    {
        public Nullable<double> Field1 { get; set; }
        [Remote("ValidateAmount", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Field1, Field2")]
        [Display(Name = "BALANCE AMT")]
        public Nullable<double> Field2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller ValidationController.cs

```
namespace MvcTest.Controllers
{
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        Entities1 db = new Entities1();
        public static NameValueCollection messagesCol;
        public String errorField;
        public String errorMessage;

        public JsonResult ValidateAmount(CUSTS custs)
        {
            CUSTS cus = new CUSTS();

            if (custs.Field2< custs.Field1)
            {
                loadMessages();

                String[] errMsg = new String[1];
                errMsg = messagesCol.GetValues("OES0373");
                string st=errMsg[0] + ". \r\n The Balance amount is:" + custs.XWIDV0 + " & the Credit Limit is:" + custs.XWGIVA;
                return Json(st,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                //return new ActionResult(errMsg[0] + ". \r\n The Balance amount is:" + custs.XWIDV0 + " & the Credit Limit is:" + custs.XWGIVA);
            }
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //return ActionResult.Success;
        }

        public static void loadMessages()
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Models\\messages_en.properties"));
            String fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();

            String[] sepr = new string[] { "\r\n" };
            String[] lines = fileContents.Split(sepr, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            messagesCol = new NameValueCollection();
            int numMessages = lines.Length;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                int indx = line.IndexOf('=');

                if (indx != -1)
                {
                    messagesCol.Add(line.Substring(0, indx), line.Substring(indx + 1));
                }
            }

            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to ask two things

1. Is this way of achieving the required functionality is correct. What else could be done.
2. Another Problem that I have just diagnosed is that post method in the form in the view is executing irrespective of the validation whether it is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to achieve the functionality by using
    [Remote] 
attribute. this is how I have done it.

The model CUSTS.cs

```
namespace MvcTest.Models
```

{

```
public partial class CUSTS
{

    public Nullable<double> Field1{ get; set; }
    [Remote("ValidateAmount", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Field1, Field2")]
    [Display(Name = "BALANCE AMT")]
    public Nullable<double> Field2{ get; set; }
}
```

}

The controller ValidationController.cs

```
namespace MvcTest.Controllers
```

{
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        Entities1 db = new Entities1();
        public static NameValueCollection messagesCol;
        public String errorField;
        public String errorMessage;

```
    public JsonResult ValidateAmount(CUSTS custs)
    {
        CUSTS cus = new CUSTS();

        if (custs.Field2< custs.Field1)
        {
            loadMessages();

            String[] errMsg = new String[1];
            errMsg = messagesCol.GetValues("OES0373");
            string st=errMsg[0] + ". \r\n The Balance amount is:" + custs.XWIDV0 + " & the Credit Limit is:" + custs.XWGIVA;
            return Json(st,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //return new ActionResult(errMsg[0] + ". \r\n The Balance amount is:" + custs.XWIDV0 + " & the Credit Limit is:" + custs.XWGIVA);
        }
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return ActionResult.Success;
    }


    public static void loadMessages()
    {
        StreamReader sr =
            new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Models\\messages_en.properties"));
        String fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();

        String[] sepr = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        String[] lines =
            fileContents.Split(sepr, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        messagesCol = new NameValueCollection();
        int numMessages = lines.Length;

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            int indx = line.IndexOf('=');

            if (indx != -1)
            {
                messagesCol.Add(line.Substring(0, indx), line.Substring(indx + 1));
            }
        }

        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Now I want to ask two things 
1. Is this way of achieving the required functionality is correct. What else could be done.
  2. Another Problem that I have just diagnosed is that post method in the form in the view is executing irrespective of the validation whether it is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have done it:

1)override GetValidators() in a cusotm implementation of DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider . Here you can read your file and decide on which validators to attach to the property being looked at.

2) write you're own ValidationAttributes and override the IsValid() method to implement the custom rules you want. You can also override FormatErrorMessage to format the error message any way you want to. You can even have those propagated to the client side by implementing IClientValidatable in your ValidationAttributes.

3) Register the provider in Application_Start() in Global.asax with

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new VProvider());
```

The custom implementation of DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider can be something like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
{
     IEnumerable<ModelValidator> toRet = new Collection<ModelValidator>();
     string prop = metadata.PropertyName;
     //get the custom rules you want applied from database or file or any other storage 
     AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false; //to remove implicit required from value types if you want to
     //Determine what attributes you want to apply to this property
     attributes = new List<Attribute>() { new MyCustomAttribute() };
     //Ask the base class to construct the list of validators to return to the caller
     return = base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes);
}
```

the custom attribute would look something like:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute:ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //perform whatever tests you want here and return true/false
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        //do some formatting
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var r = new ModelClientValidationRule
                    {
                       ErrorMessage = "Some error message",
                       ValidationType = "customType",
                    };
        r.ValidationParameters.Add(paramName,paramValue);

        yield return r;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like is that you need to use resource files with the error messages, then use the built-in attribute parameters for localization, such as:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(MyResourcesNameSpace.ResourcesFile),    
     ErrorMessageResourceName="FirstNameRequiredKey")]
```

Comment: I thought the OP mentioned that he does not want the errors specified on the model.

Comment: @JTMon - it's difficult to understand what he meant, but I took it to mean that he didn't want to hard code the error message in the data model, but wanted to lookup the error message instead.  That's what using a resource does.  But without further clarification it's hard to tell.

Comment: I know what you mean which is why I started my comment with "I Thought" :) but I counted on " I want these error no to be defined in the model" and "have a special file that contains various validation error no and their corresponding validation error msg" in combination to deduce that he wanted either custom errors or native ones to be defined in an separate file as opposed to on the model. Kind of a dynamic Validation/error checking. Or it could be because I just finished implementing such a thing :)

Comment: All I wnat is to have a file say Validation_error_list.txt which has error_no and corresponding errror_msg  
eg:-  err2101           Your credit limit has expired  err2102           Your previous payment is still pending  ......etc.  Now what i want is to have client side validation for the same.which firstly check for its validity and if not valid may forward the error msg.

Comment: @MohsinAkhtar And how are you going to determine that err2101 needs to be thrown? if in a custom check, then my answer above applies directly to what you need